# Angular JS Animation Not Working

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I'm trying to show/hide a details field in angular js. The details show and hide, but there is no animation for some reason.

```
<div class="directoryEntry" ng-repeat="listing in listings">
        <span class="category">{{listing.category}}</span>
                    ...
        <a ng-click="sElement = $index" href="javascript:void(0)">Member Details ></a>
        <div ng-show="$index == sElement" ng-animate="{show: 'details-show', hide: 'details-hide'}">{{listing.details}}</div>
    </div>
```

This is the CSS:

```
.details-show, .details-hide {
-webkit-transition:all linear 0.5s;
-moz-transition:all linear 0.5s;
-ms-transition:all linear 0.5s;
-o-transition:all linear 0.5s;
transition:all linear 0.5s;
}

.details-show.details-show-active,
.details-hide {
opacity:1;
}

.details-hide.details-hide-active,
.details-show {
opacity:0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you have 2 different classes instead of just a state class? like : `.details : {} .details.is-hidden {} .details.is-visible {}`

Comment: I don't know, I don't know what you're talking about.

Comment: You have one element with 2 classes `.details-show` and `.details-hide` and 2 different state classes `.details-show-active` and `.details-hide-active` what does it achieve? or can it be simplified.

Comment: I'm not concerned that it can be simplified right now.  I just need to get it working with animation.

Comment: Well, simplifying will help you to get the animations to work, unless `ng-show` isn't being evaluated, because, it should be just a straight forward class toggle with transitions handled by css. Also make sure you're using `$scope.apply()` to update  `ng-show` vars

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you include the ngAnimation module inside your application. You should add the [correct script](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.16/angular-animate.js) in your HTML and require it in your application module declaration like this:

```
angular.module('yourApp', ['ngAnimate']);
```

You should also use the `.ng-hide-add` and `.ng-hide-remove` for your animations. To get more information, you can consult this example in the AngularJS documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow#usage_animations